# jooQ + JPA + Hibernate + postgresql has problems with casts (::). ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jooq

Our previous stack was JPA + Hibernate to access our postgresql database. We knew that we should cast types with `cast(someUUID AS text)` instead of `someUUID::text`. ([why?](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-do-solve-the-postgresql-cast-operator-issue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/))

Recently we added jooQ to generate type safe sql for more complicated statements. But unfortunately jooQ generates casts (::) which are not compatible with JPA+Hibernate.

`create.renderInlined(/*...*/).replace("::", "\\:\\:")`  doesn't work because parameters which contain "::" are replaced as well.

Is there any way to tell jooQ to use the other syntax or just replace the casts?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Parameter names should start with single colon, don't they?

Comment: Yes, they do. I don't know the implementation details, but this causes the conflict. If you control the sql, you can just escape the casts or use the cast (..) syntax. But with jooQ I couldn't find a way to hook in or configure the output.

Comment: Why do you use `renderInlined()` rather than `render()`? By default, it seems you'd probably want to produce bind variables in your generated SQL, even with JPA/Hibernate's native queries...

Comment: We have quite dynamic statements. I thought that it would be less error prone to define/insert the params where they are used. Instead defining them and later separately set the values. But this would definitely be a solution.